# Read data from Textfile using Java

Tags: java, file-io, readfile

I have a problem in create program which reading the text-file in particular manner.
A text-file which have data in below format.

```
Id|Name|City  
1|Mack|London
```

And another text-file which contain name & age like,

```
Name|Age  
Mack|31
```

Now I want to find out all data *who's city is London and age is 31*.

How to get it?

Comment: Did you try your favorite search engine first?

Comment: @Sanchit yes i have try to find on Google but not result

Comment: Just a hint: your actual question shouldn't have ANY relationship with file IO. File IO is used to read data from files, and store them as objects in memory. Once you have the objects in memory, you can find the objects you want.

Comment: Which part of this task are you having trouble with? Reading a text file?  Parsing it into records?  Storing those records in memory?  Searching the record lists looking for matching name keys?  You will need to narrow the problem down and ask a specific question, to get a good answer.

Comment: @DuncanJones Buddy i tried code for reading only one file but i want data from combine files.

Comment: Given the end result required, I'd tend to store the records in a DB.  Search then becomes trivial.

Comment: @AndrewThompson how to store result in DB?Please Help

Comment: *"i tried code for reading only one file but i want data from combine files."*  Do the stuff you did to read one file, but do it twice.  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) of your closest attempt & again, ask a *specific* question.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why you dont use a database. The files you use, the delimiters etc, they are the main reason why databases are created. And what you asked is a simple JOIN operation. If you insist on using files instead of database, you need a long algorithm for that operation which is predefined in SQL language.

Comment: This answer should really be a comment, but +1 to get you closer to the rep. needed to comment.